# Detect if the request is an ESI - Symfony2

Tags: symfony

This may not be possible, and if that's the case then I'll have to look for another solution, so please let me know if it can't be done.

I know I can get the Request Type which is either 1=master or 2=sub-request, but is there a way to detect if the request is an ESI request?

My understanding is that an ESI will always be a sub-request, but there are many different sub requests. I need my Response Listener to detect which ones are definitely ESI requests.

Normally my ESI requests will come from a {{render_esi() }} call in Twig.

Of course I can attach a query param or something, but I would rather be able to detect without this if it's possible.

Comment: So, basically the same controller can be included via ESI and can be used as a "master request" (i.e. can be called via route)? If so, are you using rendering the ESI via `render_esi(controller('BundleName:Controller:action'))`?

Answer (score 2):

I realise this question is super old and you've probably found a solution since then, however, recently I faced the same issue and the way around it was to replace the `FragmentListener` class with my own and set an attribute on the `Request` object. Thanks to @Johnny for the `FragmentListener` hint.

Something like the following:

php class:

```
<?php
namespace Your\Namespace\Here;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener as SymfonyFragmentListener;

class FragmentListener extends SymfonyFragmentListener
{
    private $signer;
    private $fragmentPath;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __construct(UriSigner $signer, $fragmentPath = '/_fragment')
    {
        parent::__construct($signer, $fragmentPath);

        $this->signer = $signer;
        $this->fragmentPath = $fragmentPath;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (
            $request->attributes->has('_controller')
            || $this->fragmentPath !== rawurldecode($request->getPathInfo())
        ) {
            return;
        }
        $event->getRequest()->attributes->set('esi', true);

        parent::onKernelRequest($event);
    }
}
```

service definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container 
    xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd"
    >

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="fragment.listener.class">Your\Namespace\Here\FragmentListener</parameter>
    </parameters>
</container>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to take a look at the [Fragment Listener](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/FragmentListener.html) for an idea about how Symfony2 detects ESI requests.

You also mention that "Normally my ESI requests will come from a {{render_esi() }} call in Twig." How about wrapping the render_esi function with your own that fires off an event that you could listen for. This would practically be what Fragment Listener does.

Hope that helps a bit. I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to do this.