# Nearly completed - just need to finish Twig extension to render ESI - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to create a Twig extension and use this:

```
{{ new_func(route-name) }}
```

To do the same thing as:

```
{{ render_esi(url(route-name)) }}
```

...but with some adjustments

It's nearly done but it's this line that needs to be changed, but I can't see how I can call an ESI from this code (outside of Twig):

```
return $environment->render($route);   /// needs to receive route and render an ESI
```

-

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\MyBundle\Twig;

class NewTwigFunction extends \Twig_Extension
{

    private $request;

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->request = $container->get('request');
    }

    public function getFunctions() {

        return array(
            'new_func' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'newFunction', array('needs_environment' => true) )
        );

    }

    public function newFunction(\Twig_Environment $environment, $route) {

        $r = $this->request;

        return $environment->render($route);

    }

    public function getName() {

        return "new_func";

    }

 }
```

Comment: Is this question really different from the other one you posted 3h ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907576/detect-if-the-request-is-an-esi-symfony2

Comment: whats wrong with the `standalone` option of `render` ? Symfony2 already handle esi pretty well.

Comment: I'm not saying there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: ok, so, please excuse my question, but what is the interest of such an extension?

Comment: This is a possible solution to the other question (posted at the top of these comments). Either way both questions remain unanswered, so I need to do one of them. Surely this should be really simple??

Comment: Yeah, I think you should have a look to the twig [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html)

Comment: I can't see how that can help as that is done in Twig (unless I'm mistaken). Thanks for help though

Comment: sorry, then, i think I dont undertand the question. never mind

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow why would you need this, but I think it's great as an example of an abstract question:

## How do I track down & extend core functionality of Symfony2?

### Finding the functionality

Seems that you're having trouble finding where is this `render_esi` executed, so let's tackle that!

This doesn't seem like a standard Twig feature, so it must be an extension, just like the one you're creating.

It should be located somewhere in Symfony2 core files, so we start looking into `vendor/symfony/src` folder. Since we already know that we're dealing with an extension of Twig, `Component` folder is out of the question (because Twig is a separate library from Symfony2 core components).

So we've narrowed it down to `Bridge` and `Bundle`. If we look inside them then we see `Bundle/TwigBundle` or `Bridge/Twig`. We also know that Symfony2 developers follow a strict code/architecture style, so we know exactly which folder to look for - `Extension`. Now it's just a matter of checking them both.

Long story short we find what we're looking for in `vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/HttpKernelExtension`, where we see a `render_*` function. Jackpot!

### Extending the functionality

Before changing anything, we need to first emulate what's already there, so we create something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Fragment\FragmentHandler;

class NewTwigFunction extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $handler;

    public function __construct(FragmentHandler $handler)
    {
        $this->handler = $handler;
    }

    public function getFunctions() 
    {
        return array(
            'new_func' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'newFunction', array('is_safe' => array('html')) )
        );
    }

    public function newFunction($uri, $options = array()) 
    {
        return $this->handler->render($uri, 'esi', $options);
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return "new_func";
    }

 }
```

Now when you call

`{{ new_func(url(route-name)) }}`

you should see same results as

`{{ render_esi(url(route-name)) }}`

But we still need to get rid of the `url` part.
Easy as pie, we just add the `router` service to our extension! Now our extension could look like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Fragment\FragmentHandler;

class NewTwigFunction extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $handler;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(FragmentHandler $handler, Router $router)
    {
        $this->handler = $handler;
        $this->router  = $router;
    }

    public function getFunctions() 
    {
        return array(
            'new_func' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'newFunction', array('is_safe' => array('html')) )
        );
    }

    public function newFunction($routeName, $options = array()) 
    {
        $uri = $this->router->generate($routeName);

        return $this->handler->render($uri, 'esi', $options);
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return "new_func";
    }

 }
```

and `{{ new_func(route-name) }}` should work as expected.

### Hooking in-between

The way I understood it, you want almost the same functionality as `render_esi`, but with slight changes to output.
So that means that we need to hook somewhere in-between `return` and `$this->handler->render($uri, $strategy, $options);`.

How deep down the rabbit hole we need to go depends on the change.

For example, if you want to alter `Response` object before it's turned into actual `html string`, you need to find the spot where it's turned in the first place. A good bet would be to look into `FragmentHandler`:

```
protected function deliver(Response $response)
{
    if (!$response->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Error when rendering "%s" (Status code is %s).', $this->request->getUri(), $response->getStatusCode()));
    }

    if (!$response instanceof StreamedResponse) {
        return $response->getContent();
    }

    $response->sendContent();
}
```

Got it! Now you just need to extend `FragmentHandler::deliver()` and pass your implementation of it into your twig extenion.

### Tracking down configuration

You have to understand that Symfony2 core code is not that different from what you write in your everyday life, it still abides by its own rules.

For example, when normally creating a Twig extension in Symfony2 you need to configure it as a service, right? Well, Symfony2 core extensions are configured in the same way. You just need to find where the configuration files are located.

Following the logic from *Extending the functionality* we know for sure that they're not located in `Component`. `Bridge` is actually a name for a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) - not a place where you'd place your service configuration :)

So we're left with `Bundle` - and obviously that's where we find all the information we need: `vendor/symfony/src/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/config/twig.xml`

Now we simply look up how original `HttpKernelExtension` is configured and follow its lead:

```
    <service id="twig.extension.httpkernel" class="%twig.extension.httpkernel.class%" public="false">
        <argument type="service" id="fragment.handler" />
    </service>
```

Transforming it into a more commonly used `.yml` format, our extension config could look like this:

```
new_func:
    class: Acme\Bundle\MyBundle\Twig\NewTwigFunction
    arguments:
        - "@fragment.handler"
        # Uncomment when implementing code from 2nd example
        # - "@router"
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
    public: false
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great and I've just started working my way through this, but in my services.yml I need to pass an argument that FragmentHandler is happy with. If I pass '@service_container' then it returns this error: Argument 1 passed to NewTwigFunction::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Fragment\FragmentHandler, instance of appDevDebugProjectContainer given... I've tried passing @handler, and various others but nothing works

Comment: @user2143356 updated answer with information about tracking configuration. Also keep in mind that all examples are illustrative and might not work when copied 1:1 :)

Comment: @fragment.handler did the job - working on the rest now. Thanks

Comment: Inori, there is no doubt about it you are the King of Symfony2. Nobody anywhere can seem to anwser this question, and I would appreciate if you could lend 2 minutes of your expertise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937574/symfony2-extend-rememberme-success-handler

Comment: Tip: you should add your custom FragmentHandler that inherits HIncludeFragmentRenderer or EsiFragmentRenderer and just override the deliver method.